# Comparing array of objects in Powershell

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, powershell

I have two different objects in `Powershell`:

- One is using a `"Project"` class instantiated with `New-Object`. Each of these contain 2 `properties`.
- The second one is just an array of strings.

Now, I would like to remove the projects in the array of `Project` that are not in the second array.

For, instance. In `Linq`, I would do something like this:

```
var result = from item in arrayOfStrings
             from project in arrayOfProjects
             where project.Property2 == item
             select project;
```

This query would get me anything in the first list that is not in the second one.

What I have tried without success:

```
$result = $projects | Where-Object { $_.Property2 -eq $arrayOfStrings | Select-Object }
```

Thank you

**Edit**

The class looks like this:

```
public class Project
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Guid {get; set;}
}
```

The second array is just filled with some Guids. I want to get a `$queryResult` with the Projects that are in the second array.

Comment: Can you not edit the question and show the structure of the objects? Hard to know what you're asking otherwise. However, I don't think you'll need the final `Select-Object`, there `Where-Object` will do the "select"

Comment: I added the class in the edit. Yes, I guess I won't need it. But, I am not too familiar with Powershell

Comment: `$projects | Where-Object Property2 -in $arrayOfStrings`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$projects | Where-Object { $arrayOfStrings -Contains $_.Name }
```

Or using the "in" operator:

```
$projects | Where-Object { $_.Name -in $arrayOfStrings }
```

Comment: Note that `-in` started in PowerShell version 3.

Comment: Thanks so much to both of you